# Do cookies work when html is embedded into a google sites website?

Tags: html, cookies, google-sites

I have created a game in google sites and would like to use cookies to track the player's highscore. I am not sure if google sites allows cookies in embedded html. I checked the code of the google sites page and figured out that my embedded html is actually stored as an iframe, which as far as I know, does not allow cookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be difficult to implement it since like you said its in an iframe and the domain of the iframe is dynamically generated. A similar issue is raised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55886475/use-of-localstorage-and-indexeddb-in-new-google-sites-embed-html-doesnt-work). An alternative option would be to create a web app on firebase and link it with your google sites, but this could be slightly different from your initial idea of keeping track of user's score on the browser.

Comment: It also does not allow alert() to work if that is important